# Fatal error: Cannot declare class

Tags: php

I can not understand why php gives me an error

> "Fatal error: Cannot declare class rex\builder\RexBuilder, because the
>   name is already in use in /var/www/site2.dev/App/rex/RexBuilder.php on
>   line 12"

RexBuilder static class, and it is called only 1 time.
I did a search on the project, no longer classes with the same name.

```
    <?php

namespace rex\builder;

require_once 'Router.php';

use rex\router\Router;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class RexBuilder {

    public static function collector($array) {
        $router = new Router();
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            $router->get($val->getMethod(), $val->getInterfaces(), $val->getHandler());
        }
        $router->init();
    }
}
?>
```

Call the class in index.php

```
RexBuilder::collector(array(
new BuildModel('POST', '/api/v1/user/register', new \api\register\Registration()),
new BuildModel('POST', '/api/v1/user/login', new \api\login\Login())));
```

More This class is not used

Comment: `/var/www/site2.dev/App/rex/RexBuilder.php` we want this file  code (full and comment infront-of line 12)

Comment: @Anant, add full code

Comment: `class RexBuilder` is conflicting (because it seems second time you are trying to define it) so check once your all namespaces. Did you get this error in `index.php`?

Comment: @Anant,
I do not know because this was the error or not, but now it was gone.

I lay the root directory index.php and index.html.

The only challenge was index.php RexBuilder which gathered url's api.

In index.html were calls to these url's through js.

I changed the name of index.php on api.php.
Now there is no error.

Comment: There was no error in index.php.

Comment: great that your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is thrown because of the `use rex\router\Router;` duplicate classes.

When you are writing `use namespace..` it means you can go directly to that namespace like it is your current namespace

Lets take a look at the next code:

We'll create a file and declare that it belongs to *namespace classes\a*

```
//file: a.php
<?php

namespace classes\a;

class A{

}
```

now lets create another file `b.php` (and declare it belongs to namespace classes\b but it means nothing for the example)

```
namespace classes\b;

require_once "a.php";

use classes\a; //Notice that I'm using this namespace, it means I can use it directly

class A{

}
```

Generates the error

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class classes\b\A because the name is already in use in

We have to solutions possible:

First: remove the `use` tag and write the namespace directly

```
class A{
    function __constructor(){
        $instance = new classes\a\A();
    }
}
```

Second, give it alias

```
use classes\a as out_a;

class A{
    function __constructor(){
        $instance = new out_a\A();
    }
}
```

For your code, just remove the `use` or give it an alias.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is certainly because you include the `RexBuilder.php` file two times instead of one.

If you call the file by this way : `include('RexBuilder.php');` or this way `require('RexBuilder.php');` please change it by `include_once('RexBuilder.php');` or `require_once('RexBuilder.php');` which only allows ONE call of the file.

Comment: thanks for the help...sometimes we do stupid mistakes indeed!!